# Months Appear in Backwards Order

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame, lets call is `month`, that includes a column called `date` that has the month in which each observation occured. When I was making a graph in plotly the months appeard in alphabetical order instead of in sequential order so to correct that I used the following:

```
month$date <- factor(month$date, levels = unique(as.character(month$date)))
```

However, when I did this the months appeared backwards, that is December to Janurary instead of January to December. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ordering in the occurrence of unique 'date' elements in the 'month' column .  If the 'date' column includes the full name of 'month', then make use of the default 'month.name' `vector` which is already in the correct order, specify that in the `levels`

```
month$date <- factor(month$date, levels = month.name)
```

where

```
month.name
#[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September"
#[10] "October"   "November"  "December"
```

EDIT: Based on @GregorThomas comments